# Installing software on live USB so I can access it from a live session

Tags: software-installation, live-usb

I use Ubuntu on live USB so that I can use Ubuntu whereever I go. I save all of my files onto a second USB (documents, pictures, etc).

I want to use software called Sweet Home 3D wherever I go.

I downloaded the `.tgz` file and extracted it to my documents USB. How do I install this software on the same USB so that I can access it from my live USB?

Comment: I don't want persistent USB, I want a fresh reboot every time, I want to save files and software onto other usb.

Comment: Persistence is triggered by the word "persistent" in grub.cfg, text.cfg, txt.cfg or syslinux.cfg. if you remove the word persistent the drive will act like a Live USB but will retain any programs installed when it was persistent. A persistent session can be started by typing <space> persistent after pressing F6 while booting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the program from where it's mounted, no install needed, provided the mount of the device did not have the "noexe" qualifier on it preventing execution of programs.

Check how the USB is mounted -- in a terminal (ctrl-alt-t to start one) type:

```
mount
```

Locate the USB, and confirm that there is no "noexe" in that line.
If there is, you'll have to issue a remount command yourself to remove that qualifier.

Now you can run the program by typing its full path (/media/usr/xxxx/yyyy/sweethome3d) or  add the program's location to your PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/media/usr/xxxx/yyyy/
```

Consider using a home-rw file or partition to allow persistence on just your home directory.  That might be able to be on the second USB (file home-rw with ext2 filesystem).  The persistence USBs will scan FAT filesystems  for possible casper-rw and home-rw files to mount, but both are optional.

---

Programs may be run from anywhere, unless steps are taken to prevent them from running.  Your "Documents" USB must be mounted for you to copy files to it, so locate the program on it and try to run it.  Either the full path to the program (e.g. /media/username/..whatever../sweethome3d  or if your current directory is set to that location, try ./sweethome3d (note the dot slash in the name). Unless you explicitly have "." in your path, that ./ is necessary.

Comment: I have extracted the .tgz file and have that on a separate USB are you saying the software Doesn't need to be installed on the USB?